# webkit-transform Do not work when added in two different checkboxs

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a problem that might seem stupid!

What I simply want is to have a div with camera opened, and two checkboxes, one to invert colors and one to switch camera direction, but when I have the two checkbox inputs, only the second one works and the first don't, but if I keep any of them alone, it works. How can I solve that?
Thanks

```css
input#lightswitch:checked + .main > .video-container {
 -webkit-filter: invert(1);
}
input#direction:checked + .main > .video-container {
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
 transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="lightswitch" />
<input type="checkbox" id="direction" />

<div class="main">
  <h2>Lights</h2>
  <div class="features">
   <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
   <p class="last">Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="video-container">
   <video id="v" class="video-container"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this code doesn't reproduce the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're using the *adjacent sibling combinator* or `+` for both `input` elements, while you should be using the *general sibling combinator* or `~` for the first one (`#lightswitch`), or even better use it on both (if it happens that some other elements come before the `.main` div).

The difference between them is that the `+` only selects an element that comes **right after** the element on which that selector is being used on, while with the `~` that's not the case, can be any number of other sibling elements between and it will still select it. That's why the `#direction` input element works fine, but the `#lightswitch` doesn't.

```css
#lightswitch:checked ~ .main > .video-container {
  -webkit-filter: invert(1);
  color: #0f0; /* inverts the color to #f0f when checked */
}

#direction:checked ~ .main > .video-container { /* recommended, but can also leave the + selector if you don't plan to add any elements before the .main div */
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="lightswitch">
<input type="checkbox" id="direction">

<div class="main">
  <h2>Lights</h2>
  <div class="features">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p class="last">Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="video-container">
    test
    <video id="v" class="video-container"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```